# How to set Html id based on Model item id

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have some code like:

```
<table>         
    @foreach (var invoiceLine in Model.Invoice.InvoiceLine)) {
        <tr class="subheader">
             <td>
                 <div class="approval">
                     <span>Office sign off:</span>
                          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfficeUser.Name)
                     <span id="officeapprovalspan">@(item.OfficeApproved.HasValue ? (item.OfficeApproved.Value ? "Accepted" : "On Hold") : "Please Approve")</span>
                 </div>
             </td>
```

Well the span with `id="officeapprovalspan"` I'm wanting to set it's id so that it's officapprovalspan"x" where x is the current item invoiceLineId.

So when invoiceLineId=3 I would ideally want the span id to be `id="officeapprovalspan3"`

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I'd add that it is not normal for views to have logic `(item.OfficeApproved.HasValue ? (item.OfficeApproved.Value ? "Accepted" : "On Hold")` and that this should really be a value that comes from the viewmodel directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<span id="officeapprovalspan@(invoiceLine.invoiceLineId)">@(item.OfficeApproved.HasValue ? (item.OfficeApproved.Value ? "Accepted" : "On Hold") : "Please Approve")</span>
```

or

```
<span id="@("officeapprovalspan" + invoiceLine.invoiceLineId)">@(item.OfficeApproved.HasValue ? (item.OfficeApproved.Value ? "Accepted" : "On Hold") : "Please Approve")</span>
```

Comment: I use this with ternary operators and classes all the time `<div class="@( (requiresFolder) ? "" : "ui-helper-hidden")">`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
<span id="officeapprovalspan@invoiceLine.InvoiceLineId">
```

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't evaluate the invoicelineId

Comment: @AnonyMouse How do you mean it doesn't evaluate invoicelineid?

Comment: Well it literally creates the markup <span id="officeapprovalspan@invoiceLine.InvoiceLineId">
where what I want is <span id="officeapprovalspan3">

Comment: Ahh I see. Patricks solution should do the trick then I think!